# Postgresql system tables frequently seen in autovacuum and DDL operations are taking time

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 11 on Azure and constantly seeing postgresql system tables showing up in `autovacuum`. I also see DDL statements take longer than what they used to (logged table or unlogged).

Some of the system tables seen frequently running an `autovacuum`:

```
pg_attribute
pg_depend
pg_shdepend
pg_statistic
pg_type
```

Very frequent DDL operations are performed by our application in the form of tables that get created and dropped very frequently (probably, 50-100 DDL statements in a minute).

The database had been performing well enough since more than a year. However, only recently have things seem to have deteriorated.

When does `autovacuum` get triggered for system tables? Is there something that can be done to improve the situation other than doing a `VACUUM FULL` for a database?

How can I troubleshoot more to fix the underlying cause or tweak parameters to maintain it effectively?

Comment: "*that get created and dropped very frequently (probably, 50-100 DDL statements in a minute)*" - why would you do that?

Comment: Those tables have probably gotten extremely bloated, which is not surprising for "50-100 DDL statements in a minute".  I would be more curious about how it didn't happen sooner.  You can target VACUUM FULL just towards those tables, not necessary to do the entire database.

Comment: Is it safe to do a `VACUUM FULL` on postgresql system tables? The documentation scares me a little.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right. It's the kind of workload that our application has (which we're unable to modify significantly because of historic reasons). It's an event based system where set of events are batched together and a bunch of SQL runs over it creating and dropping tables in between. What could be done to make them in a better state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that these catalog tables have lots of dead row versions if you keep creating and dropping tables. Unfortunately it is not possible to configure autovacuum to run fast on a certain catalog table, so you will have to change the setting globally:

```
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
```

In case these tables are already bloated (which is likely), you will have to take down time and rebuild the catalog tables:

```
VACUUM (FULL) pg_attribute;  -- repeat for the other tables
```

Try changing your workload so that you don't need to create and drop tables quite that often.